# How to convert a block of string to elements in array in Java

Tags: java

```
String file_path = "src/input.txt";
    String everything;
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file_path));
    try {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = br.readLine();

        while (line != null) {
            sb.append(line);
            sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
            line = br.readLine();
        }
        everything = sb.toString();
    } finally {
        br.close();
    }
```

I used this code to read input.txt file and store it into a string named everything.
This is my input.txt

> 1 2 10 I
>
> 3 1 11 C
>
> 1 2 19 R
>
> 1 2 21 C
>
> 1 1 25 C

What method should I use if I wanna covert String everything to arrays which contain both integers and letters ?

I tried using to print integer 10 in the first row.:

```
char arry[];    
arry=everything.toCharArray();    
System.out.print(arry[4]);
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: why not use String ArrayList?

Comment: your concept are zero. First try to read some material about bytes and chars. No point of getting direct answers from stackoverflow.

Comment: Your code is not a serious attempt to solve your problem. Show us your reasonable attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

If you are using jdk8

To char array

```
public static void readLines() {

    String file_path = "src/input.txt";
    ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(file_path))) {
            stream.forEach(lines::add);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    String everything = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++) {
      if(lines.get(i).length()>0){ // uncomment if you don not want to remove empty lines
          everything = everything +  lines.get(i);
      }
    }


    char[] chars = everything.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i <chars.length ; i++) {
        System.out.println("Char at index "+i+"; "+ chars[i]);
    }
}
```

To String array

```
public static void readLines() {

    String file_path = "src/input.txt";
    ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(file_path))) {
            stream.forEach(lines::add);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String[] everything = new String[lines.size()];

    for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++) {
       everything[i] = lines.get(i);
    }
}
```

Older way

```
 public static void readFile() {

    ArrayList<String> allStrings = new ArrayList<>();


    String file_path = "src/input.txt";
    String everything;
    BufferedReader br = null;
    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file_path));

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = br.readLine();
        while (line != null) {
            if (line.length() > 0) {
                allStrings.add(line);
            }
            sb.append(line);
            sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
            line = br.readLine();
        }
        everything = sb.toString();


        //Convert to array
        String[] everyString = new String[allStrings.size()];
        System.out.println("Everything: " + everything);
        for (int i = 0; i < allStrings.size(); i++) {
            everyString[i] = allStrings.get(i);
        }


        //Print Array
        for (int i = 0; i < allStrings.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("Index: " + everyString[i]);
        }

        br.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```